# How to make the dropdown menu vertical

Tags: javascript, css

I have a horizontal menu at the top of the page and I want a vertical drop down menu to appear below one of the horizontal menu items. The menus are not connected ... the code that generates the horizontal menu at the top of the page is completely separate from the code for the vertical menu I want to appear below.

But, the menu is appearing horizontal. What do I have to do to make each menu item appear vertically.

I have a fiddle at [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mc7kLc8c/)

Here is a bit of the code as I have to paste something here ..

```
#dvMenu ul 
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
}
```

If you look at the fiddle, run it and click on 'Link Two' - the sub-menu appears - but it is horizontal. What do I have to do to get it to appear vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float: left` from `#dvMenu li`.

Check your [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mc7kLc8c/1/).

Comment: Thanks for that - been driving me nuts for three hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the clear property to your stylesheet, then the floating elements won't be able to float side by side anymore.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

updated fiddle

```
#dvMenu ul li 
{
  float: left;
  clear:both;
  display: block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 21px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mc7kLc8c/2/

Comment: Thanks for that. Interesting - removing float:left - as the answer from LinkinTed - works. Adding clear:both works too. CSS baffles me.

Comment: Haha, I understand. Elements float horizontally, so by floating them all, they were floating horizontally side by side- even with the display: block; in effect. You didn't need to float these elements to position them where they were, and by floating them all you effectively made them run horizontally. So removing the "float" keyword definitely solves the problem here. Given you wanted to float them for some reason, the "clear" property prevents elements from floating alongside one another, which forces the elements to stack in their block orientation. That's why they both solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

change `position:` to `absolute` from `relative` in your css

Answer (score 0):

remove `display: inline;` from `#navcontainer ul li`